# WebStorm-like TypeScript method overrides in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

When overriding TypeScript methods in WebStorm, IDE completes method with access modifier (`public`, `protected` or `private`), return value type, parameters and parameter types:
[image]
[image]

VS Code only completes parameters:
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to make VS Code complete method overrides like WebStorm does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not presently supported in VS Code.

There was a feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58193, but it was closed in favor of adding general snippet completion (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25207) which is still in progress.